# Controlling Current in a Ciruit

Tags: current, resistors

By way of resistors, I was wondering if there is any easy way or product in the market to be able to control the current in a circuit without having to take apart the circuit and put in new resistors.(So something with a dial perhaps so that I can change the current instantly)

Comment: For your safety, I suggest you to add more detail on the kind of circuit you are trying to modify. Especially if it is working at potentially lethal values of voltage or current.

Comment: Its called a programmable constant current power supply. Most benchtop supplies will do this. There are circuit designs that will do this, look up constant current

Answer (score 3):

The appropriate device is called a potentiometer or rheostat - both are variable resistors.

A potentiometer is normally used as a three-terminal device, to form a voltage divider.

Rheostats are normally two-terminal devices and often have lower resistance and are capable of handling higher power than potentiometers (but pots are often used as rheostats).